# problems with netbeans 8.1 on ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: netbeans

**NetBeans** cached too many files in *memory*. So must relaunch IDE. So I thought it is just no limitation when cache files, maybe can just keep a limited memory when handle files can help on this.[image]

Comment: Okay. What's your _question?_

Comment: netbeans ram usage more ubuntu 16.04